# call audio recording in web dialer using WebRTCConnection

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection, jssip

Iam using multiMediaRecorder to record voice of both sender and receivers at a time but iam getting only receiver voice when the call ends successfully so i want to know what is the reason how to overcome this issue and get both voices at a time.

Expecting the reason and want to get both side call recording audio.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean MediaRecorder API? Note, that you should merge both audio tracks into one before recording it. Something like [Merge two audio tracks into one track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717758/merge-two-audio-tracks-into-one-track). The resulting track contains audio from both users and will be recorded properly.